# In semiconductors, can distant particles in the same $k$-space recombine? Is this a wave phenomenon, ignoring physical separation?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals

I'm trying to understand recombination in semiconductors from a wave perspective. I'm considering the wave vector $k$ not just as momentum, but as a descriptor of the wave function's phase. In direct semiconductors, the electron and hole wave functions overlap at $k=0$, facilitating recombination. In indirect semiconductors, they're in different $k$-spaces and need to align for recombination. This alignment is achieved through phonon interactions, which I'm interpreting as interference between the electron's wave function and the lattice's vibrational waves. Does this wave-based view hold up? How can it account for wave function localization and energy conservation?

Comment: ‘Distant’ does not make much sense when wave functions extend throughout the crystal.

Comment: Yes,I do understand that. Which is why I decided to look at recombination as wave functions rather than looking at it as particles.